# How to share data between parent and child via files using pipes?

Tags: c++, pipe, dup2

I know parent and child can communicate using shared memory or via sockets. I am trying to make them communicate with each other using pipes.

I first create a child using fork and the I finally want child to read message from `stdout` which will be outputted by parent, but I was unable to this so I am trying to make them communicate from a temporary file.

After `fork`, I used `dup2` to set this file as input-fd for child and output-fd for parent. Then using sleep I ensured child reads after parent outputs.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**  argv){
    if(argc<2){
        printf("Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    int raw_desc = open("/tmp/raw.txt",O_RDWR);
    if(raw_desc<0){
        FILE* fptr = fopen("/tmp/raw.txt", "a+");
        raw_desc = open("/tmp/raw.txt",O_RDWR);
    }
    int f=fork();
    if(f==0){
        dup2(raw_desc, 0);
        sleep(3);
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        cout<<"Child got : "<<s<<endl;
    }else{
        dup2(raw_desc, 1);
        sleep(1);
        cout<<std::string(argv[1])<<endl;
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't do `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` - only include what you use instead. That header is non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I first create a child using fork and the I finally want child to read message from stdout which will be outputted by parent, but I was unable to this so I am trying to make them communicate from a temporary file.

It's easy to implement that by using `pipe` and `dup2`. Perhaps you need to read the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html).

Following is an example of how to connect parent's stdout and child's stdin with pipe.

The parent:

```c
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
int saved_stdout = dup(1); // maybe you will want to save the stdout fd and recover it later
dup2(fd[1], 1); // parent: write to fd[1]
// do writing
dup2(saved_stdout, 1); // restore stdout
```

The child:

```c
int saved_stdin = dup(0); 
dup2(fd[0], 0); // child: read from fd[0]
// do reading
dup2(saved_stdin, 0); // restore stdin
```

Comment: Got it. Edited.

Comment: @kaleid_liner You got my vote but I removed your question.